# how to fix Ubuntu no audio for applications?

Tags: ubuntu, audio, settings

Problem break down:

both system speakers and a another set of speakers appear in sound GUI.

both pass the test audio test.

system sound is null until I adjust volume on keyboard then system audio will play when volume is adjusted with mouse.

problem started after successfully playing a movie using HDMI to a tv.

I have tried restarting ALSA and pulseaudio.

Problem appears to fix itself randomly after a few days.

There maybe a connection between the problem and switching audio output device as the problem came back once I performed a restart with headphones plugged in.

Any Ideas ?

Comment: ubuntu has its on forum over at  https://askubuntu.com

Answer (score 1):

I think I found the answer to this by accident. 
Same thing happened to me - lost all application sound (though speakers still working) after connecting my macbook air (running ubuntu 18.04) to the TV over HDMI.
Solution for me was reconnecting to the TV over HDMI, going to ubunutu's Settings|Sound, switched from HDMI output to the laptop's own "Built-In Audio" speakers BEFORE disconnecting the HDMI.
Sound comes back.

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue after not installing third party software and update in the first installation step in Ubuntu 20.04 LTS.
You should just shift from gdm3 to lightdm to resolve this issue by opening the terminal and typing:

```
sudo apt-get install lightdm
sudo dpkg-reconfigure lightdm
```

After entering these commands if you are asked that only one of gdm3 or lightdm ubuntu can use then simply select lightdm when asked.
This worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

I've installed parrot os and the os didn't recognized my sound card. So explore the web for 3days. Finally I got it. It's very simple

**1-Step**

```
$ sudo dmesg
```

this will highlight firmware issues for all your devices. Check for your audio device(If any issue on firmware it will highlight in red, so it's easy to find)

**2-Step**

Then it might suggest what should you do. If not download https://github.com/thesofproject/sof-bin.git or run

```
$ git clone https://github.com/thesofproject/sof-bin.git
```

Installation guideline was on that page.

```
$ cd v1.7.x
$ sudo rsync -a sof*v1.7   /lib/firmware/intel/
$ sudo ln -s sof-v1.7      /lib/firmware/intel/sof
$ sudo ln -s sof-tplg-v1.7 /lib/firmware/intel/sof-tplg
$ sudo rsync tools-v1.7/*  /usr/local/bin
```

If this wasn't work try this:

```
$ sudo apt-get install fwupdate 
$ fwupdmgr update
$ fwupdmgr get-updates
```